# Unable to Install Redmine on Win 2008R2 .. gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

While trying to install Redmine on Windows Server 2008 R2, I struck into following error we no solutions found...

It is asking to install something, and when try to install it says it don't find it. It suggested activerecord-mysql2-adapter, but even that is not working...

I'm now starting to believe that ROR sucks....

```
C:\Ruby\Apps\Redmine>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (193:
 %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysq
l-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.8/mysql_api.so)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

C:\Ruby\Apps\Redmine>gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter' (>= 0) in any re
pository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-mysql2-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmys
ql-adapter, activerecord-jdbc-adapter, activerecord-ruby_mysql-adapter, activere
cord-fb-adapter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the `adapter` line of your `database.yml` try `gem install mysql` or `gem install mysql2`.

Comment: I tried both, it doesn't work. i'm using mysql in database file as an adapter.

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm accepting this answer just to close the question. As there are no other option to do so.

Answer (score 0):

possibly error in your database connection, verify your mysql is running and if running verify your sql connection setting in database.yml

I too faced this problem, but changing database.yml connection worked for me

Comment: hmm... thanks for your update. However, we've checked it for db connection.. and sure that it wasn't the issue. However, then we have installed the bitnami stack for Redmine. That worked for us.